How can I access the value of a promise in JavaScript?
I am using a public api for fetch data. It is returning promise.
I want to access the result of the prmise means data or info which its returning.
My code is :
    const getWeather=async ()=>{
       const data=await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=3128c60d19195ca88d4f09de900eacd2`)
    const res=  data.json();
    console.log(res)

  }

But in return I am getting as:
[[Prototype]]
: 
Promise
[[PromiseState]]
: 
"fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]
: 
Object
base
: 
"stations"
clouds
: 
{all: 75}
cod
: 
200
coord
: 
{lon: -0.1257, lat: 51.5085}
dt
: 
1716389805
id
: 
2643743
main
: 
{temp: 287.95, feels_like: 287.84, temp_min: 287.16, temp_max: 288.85, pressure: 1006, …}
name
: 
"London"
rain
: 
{1h: 2.04}

[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

How to access the [[PromiseResult]]?

You need also to await data.json()

Will const res = await data.json(); fix your peoblem by any chance?

The promises need to be 'resolved' (i.e. fulfilled, completed) in order to access the data. You can either await the call to res.getJson() (similar to how you await the fetch call), or use promise chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

The .json() function is asynchronous in JavaScript, so const res = data.json(); should be const res = await data.json();
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json for function documentation.
